# How to unselect DT row when clicking on a different one

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have this simple shiny app which renders in the text box whatever row a user selects. I want only one row to be selected at a time so I set my `DT` option to `selection = 'single'` which correctly deselects any row from the table when clicking on a different one.

And yet in the text box the name of the row I unselected by clicking on a different one is maintained and the new name is appended after the name of the previously selected row.

[image]

I noticed that in fact I can remove from the text box any previously selected row by double clicking on it (something that has visually no effect in the table).

In my actual application, I have a plotting function which will accept only one value from the table so I need to find a way to send through `input$x_rows_selected` one and only one value.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  h1('A Server-side Table'),

  fluidRow(
    column(9, DT::dataTableOutput('x3')),
    column(3, verbatimTextOutput('x4'))
  )


  ))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  # server-side processing
  mtcars2 = mtcars[, 1:8]
  output$x3 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars2, server = TRUE, selection = 'single')

  # print the selected indices
  output$x4 = renderPrint({
    s = input$x3_rows_selected
    if (length(s)) {
      cat('These rows were selected:\n\n')
      cat(s, sep = ', ')
    }
  })

})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I know that a quick fix could actually be `s <- s[length(s)]`, but I would prefer to understand how to control `input$x_rows_selected`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the CRAN version of DT (version 0.1) which has been fixed in the GitHub version (install using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT"`)